# Display only Unique rows in a column C# (razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my requirement:

Mytable:

```
Sno  Name  Phonenumber Interests

1     Ram  9500677543  SQL
2     Ram  1234567890  SQL
3     Ed   0987654343  C#
4     Ed   1357986420  C#
```

I need to get this table displayed in razor view like below:

```
Sno  Name  Phonenumber Interests

1     Ram  9500677543  SQL
2          1234567890  
3     Ed   0987654343  C#
4          1357986420
```

I'm not getting any idea. Anyone Please help me!

I'm trying like this in razor view.

```
@initialnamevalue = item.ResourceGroup_Name[0];

@for (int i = 1; i < item.ResourceGroup_Name.Count(); i++)
{
    @if (item.ResourceGroup_Name[i] == initialnamevalue)
    {
        @item.ResourceGroup_Name[i] = "";
    }
    else
    {
        initialnamevalue = @item.ResourceGroup_Name[i];
    }
}
```

but with no luck. I'm getting error @initialnamevalue does not exist in the current contect. I new to mvc, razor. Please help me out

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your controller and view code.

Comment: @JamieRees I have updated my code. Could you please see if you can help

Comment: Please post your controller code and what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a variable in razor, just put your line between accolades:

```
@{ [type] [varname] = [value]; }
```